Linear Transformation and Projections
Consider the function $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$T(\vec{u})=\text{proj}_{\vec{u}} \vec{v}$ and $T(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$ where $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{\vec{0}\}$ and $\vec{v}$ is fixed. I am trying to determine if this function is linear.
If we instead had $T(\vec{u})=\text{proj}_{\vec{v}}\vec{u}$ then it would easily follow from the formula
$$
\text{proj}_{\vec{v}}\vec{u}=\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}}\vec{v},
$$
that $T(\lambda_1\vec{u}+\lambda_2\vec{v})=\lambda_1T(\vec{u})+\lambda_2T(\vec{v})$ for all $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{\vec{0}\}$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $T$ would be linear. But I am unsure if a similar algebraic approach can be used in the case $T(\vec{u})=\text{proj}_{\vec{u}} \vec{v}$.

Note that for $u \neq 0$, $\lambda \neq 0$, $\operatorname{proj}u v = \operatorname{proj}{\lambda u} v$. The projection is onto a subspace.

We have $\text{proj}_u v = \frac{v \cdot u}{u\cdot u} u$ so for some non-zero scalar $\alpha$ we have $$T(\alpha u) = \frac{v\cdot \alpha u}{\alpha u\cdot \alpha u}\alpha u =\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2}\frac{v\cdot u}{u\cdot u}u =\frac{v\cdot u}{u\cdot u}u=T(u) \neq \alpha T(u)$$
and so the function is not linear.
